# Cell Events are not triggerred

Tags: vba, events, cell

Need a help on Cell Event Macro, I am testing Cell Event Macros and due to some reason its not triggering. Request your help to look into it

### Code

---

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Range("J8").Value = "No" Then
MsgBox "Hi"
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

---

### Code

Not Sure, where is the issue here, my expectation is to show a message box When I typed "No". However its not working

Comment: are your events turn off?

Comment: Please, try in a separate sub, the next code line 'Application.EnableEvents = True`, then test your code.

Comment: No, I kept my events on. I have even added the events on inside the code as below and its not working :( 
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = True
If Range("J8").Value = "No" Then
MsgBox "Hi"
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub

Comment: in the immediate window put `? application.EnableEvents` and hit enter.  what does it return

Comment: if your events are turned off the Worksheet_Change code will never even start.

Comment: I tried in a separte sub too, its not working

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = True
If Range("J8").Value = "No" Then
MsgBox "Hi"
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub

Comment: It Says True when I kept ?Application.enableevents

Comment: did you put that code in the worksheet code sheet or in a generic module?

Comment: I kept this code in This Workbook

Comment: That's your problem. `ThisWorkbook` isn't a sheet code module.

Comment: Then it is should be `Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)` not `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Comment: Or you should put that code in the worksheet code module

Comment: I changed the code as you requested and its still not working and also, i tried to keep the previous code in a new module and checked and its not working :(

Comment: Hi, It worked.. Sorry I didnt kept in Sheet. I tried in New Module and I tried in "Thisworkbook". Now, i kept in Sheetcode and it worked. Thanks a lot for your support

Comment: I Realized that, its going to Circular Reference
_italic_**bold
'Code'
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Set Target = Range("J8")
If Range("J8").Value = "No" Then
Call Test
Else
Exit Sub
End If
End Sub

Sub Test()

Range("K8").Value = ""

Exit Sub
End Sub



'Code'

Answer (score 2):

Below is the basic code you need and it must be installed in the code module of the sheet on which you want the action because the change event won't be noticed anywhere else.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Const TriggerCell   As String = "J8"
    
    If Target.Address(0, 0) = TriggerCell Then
        If Target.Value = "No" Then
            MsgBox "Hi"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

This code is very crude, just for demonstrating the principle which is as follows.

1. The event generates a range called `Target`. That's the cell that was changed. If you use copy/paste, many cells could be changed at the same time. Then `Target` would be a bigger range.
2. You must determine if the changed cell is of interest to you. In the above code this is done by specifying a `TriggerCell`. You might specify an entire column (but not in the above setup which can handle only one cell).
3. Since the `Target` provided by the event is the `TriggerCell` you have specified you can compare its value with your expectation and take action depending upon the result of that comparison.

Note that not `Else` or `Exit Sub` are required before the end of the sub.